# Splitting a column in dataframe into bin categories

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
avgfrequency    USER.ID
1   0.000000000 391
2   0.004081633 147389
3   0.007633588 140961
4   0.007776050 144216
5   0.031250000 142114
6   0.046849758 121811
7   0.057613169 121801
8   0.060553633 119451
9   0.067961165 121231
10  0.071428571 130791
11  0.074866310 121307
12  0.076923077 131049
13  0.083984375 120347
14  0.088471850 90723
15  0.100000000 130732
16  0.117647059 150569
17  0.125000000 138619
18  0.142857143 111617
19  0.153846154 145123
20  0.166666667 120914
21  0.174157303 64094
22  0.176470588 121937
23  0.181818182 147190
24  0.193548387 121156
25  0.196261682 122516
26  0.198795181 119618
27  0.200000000 50273
28  0.206896552 69968
29  0.208333333 117301
30  0.222222222 118837
31  0.223880597 121137
32  0.227272727 121071
33  0.230769231 142132
34  0.241379310 129447
35  0.250000000 10074
36  0.260869565 120265
37  0.261780105 29409
38  0.266666667 145135
39  0.272727273 126617
40  0.283950617 64339
41  0.285714286 112166
42  0.291666667 140435
43  0.303571429 119261
44  0.307692308 76589
45  0.312500000 124037
46  0.318181818 6429
47  0.329032258 41235
48  0.332603939 22633
49  0.333333333 3960
50  0.342857143 121545
51  0.363636364 123263
52  0.368421053 131234
53  0.369565217 53648
54  0.370370370 125421
55  0.373134328 119177
56  0.375000000 123182
57  0.376470588 119624
58  0.380952381 137438
59  0.384615385 127353
60  0.387755102 123346
61  0.388888889 122187
62  0.400000000 67889
63  0.408602151 27670
64  0.416666667 127766
65  0.421052632 126593
66  0.426470588 118098
67  0.428571429 53315
68  0.429268293 27734
69  0.431034483 120953
70  0.437500000 125508
71  0.439252336 38652
72  0.444444444 132263
73  0.450000000 134343
74  0.454545455 124898
75  0.458333333 40114
76  0.466666667 64172
77  0.470588235 115263
78  0.476190476 127675
79  0.478260870 119756
80  0.480769231 115722
```

I am trying to split avgfrequency into different bin categories. I tried using cut function:

```
user_avgfrequency$avgfrequency <- cut(user_frequency$avgfrequency,                         
breaks=quantile(user_avgfrequency$avgfrequency, probs = seq(0,370, 10)))
```

but getting an error.

Can this be done in a simpler way?

Comment: Your `cut(user_frequency$` and `user_avgfrequency` seems different, also the `probs` is outside the range

Comment: what categories do you want?